# Deserialize json object which properties can be changed each time

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following json content:

```
{
      "arguments": {
        "key" : "value"
      }
}
```

But, it can dynamically change depending on the specified configuration of the json file.

For example once can be like above, but sometimes it can be empty  `arguments: {}` or something it may be configured something like this:

```
      "arguments": {
        "someKeyName" : "someValue"
      }
```

or even:

```
      "arguments": {
        "someKeyName": "someKeyValue",
        "someKeyName2": "someKeyValue2"
      }
```

My question is, how can I handle the deserialization with Jackson's object mapper or some other alternative, without knowing what would the properties be of the arguments object each time I have to handle the deserialization ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume (spring-boot-starter+):

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Dto {

  final Map<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<>();

  public Map<String, Object> getArguments() {
    return arguments;
  }
}
```

..then we can (already) test:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class DemoJacksonApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Test
  void test1() throws JsonProcessingException {
    Dto dto = objectMapper.readValue(
        """
        {
          "arguments": {
            "key" : "value"
          }
        }
        """, Dto.class);
    assertEquals("value", dto.getArguments().get("key"));
  }

  @Test
  void test2() throws JsonProcessingException {
    Dto dto = objectMapper.readValue(
        """
        {
          "arguments": {
            "someKeyName" : "someValue"
          }
        }
        """, Dto.class);
    assertEquals("someValue", dto.getArguments().get("someKeyName"));
  }

  @Test
  void test3() throws JsonProcessingException {
    Dto dto = objectMapper.readValue(
        """
        {
          "arguments": {
            "someKeyName": "someKeyValue",
            "someKeyName2": "someKeyValue2"
          }
        }
        """, Dto.class);
    assertEquals("someKeyValue", dto.getArguments().get("someKeyName"));
    assertEquals("someKeyValue2", dto.getArguments().get("someKeyName2"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can de-serialize it into a `Map<String, Object>` and you will always get a map but its internal content would be different each time. you can do something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> data = objectReader.forType(Map.class).readValue(jsonString);
```

BTW, I wrote my own JsonUtils class which is a thin wrapper over JSON-Jackson library that simplifies a bit serializing and deserializing JSON strings. reading a simple map would look like:

```
Map<String, Object> map = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString("{\"a\": \"b\"}", Map.class);
```

But with my class you don't need to instantiate and configure `ObjectMapper` instance. Here is [JsonUtils Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). If you want to use it this class is part of Open source MgntUtils library written and maintained by me. You can get MgntUtils library as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)